From real variables function to complex variables function?
I'm confused with notations physicists using.
They change real variables $$(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in (\mathbb{R^2})^n$$ of a function to complex variables $$(z_1,z_1^*,z_2,z_2^*,...,z_n,z_n^*)\in(\mathbb{C^2})^n$$ of the function whose domain was included in $(\mathbb{R^2})^n.$
What I saw here ((2.10)-(2.30)) is, for an example, Euclidean Green functions $G_{ \alpha_1 \alpha_2...\alpha_n}$ defined on an open subset of $(\mathbb{R^2})^n$ (each index $\alpha_i$ is an element of an index set $A_0$. It's not important for now).
They rewrite $G_{ \alpha_1 \alpha_2...\alpha_n}(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ with  $G_{ \alpha_1 \alpha_2...\alpha_n}(z_1,z_1^*,z_2,z_2^*,...,z_n,z_n^*)$ and assert that under Mobius transformation $w$,
\begin{equation}
G_{ \alpha_1 \alpha_2...\alpha_n}(z_1,z_1^*,...,z_n,z_n^*)= \Pi_i (\dfrac{dw}{dz})^{h_i}(z_i)((\dfrac{dw}{dz})^*)^{\overline{h_i}}(z_i)G_{ \alpha_1 \alpha_2...\alpha_n}(w(z_1),w(z_1)^*,,...,w(z_n),w(z_n)^*)
\end{equation}
In another case, they defined translations to Schwartz space $\mathscr{S} ((\mathbb{R^2})^n)$ in the following way.
\begin{equation}
e^{-a^0H-ia^1H}f(x_1,...,x_n):= f(x_1-a,...,x_n-a) \ \ (a=(a^0,a^1)\in \mathbb{R^2})
\end{equation}
Then, they use $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ and $K=\dfrac{H+P}{2}$, and assert that $e^{-\zeta K}$ represents transformation $z\mapsto z+\zeta$, $z^*\mapsto z^*$. As a formality, denoting $\zeta$ as $\zeta = c+id\ (c,d\in\mathbb{R})$ and with $f\in\mathscr{S} \mathbb{R^2} $
\begin{align} 
(e^{-\zeta K})(t,x) &= (e^{\frac{-cH-idH-idP-cP}{2}}f)(t,x)=f(t-\frac{c+id}{2},x-\frac{d-ic}{2})\\
\end{align}
If we define $z=(first\ variable)+i(second\ variable)$, it means $z \mapsto z+\zeta$ and $z^* \mapsto z^*$. However it's wrong way to understand because $f$ is not a function on $\mathbb{C}^2$.
I'm not sure what they want to mean. Do they mean that functions are analytically continuable or other things? Why does $z^*$ appear?  Could you help me? I simplified original situation. If there is something unclear, please let me know or refer to original paper.
